# Issues compiling Tanuki Java Service wrapper version 3.1.2 under armv5tel architecture

Tags: linux, debian, compiling, java, arm

Basically I need this specific version of the Tanuki Java Service Wrapper to run a specific Java application.  I downloaded the source from the Tanuki website and I'm trying to compile it from source.

This is under a Debian Linux system `armv5tel` architecture.

It uses Ant, and there is a `build.sh` script that invokes a copy of Ant provided in the source.

However, the compilation fails with this message:

```
home/build/wrapper_3.1.2_src/build.xml:263: Error starting javah: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.tools.javah.Main.<init>([Ljava.lang.String;)
```

Comment: What JDK do you have, and what version of Ant is included in the source? The javah API has had incompatible changes over time, see [Sun bug #4824827: Change in 1.4.2-beta Javah results in Apache Ant (1.5+) <javah> task failing](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4824827)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!  JDK is the Debian package openjdk-6-jdk 6b18-1.8.7 and the version of ant is apache-ant-1.6.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use a later version of ant (the one I installed via Debian) instead of the copy provided with the source package.